# Can't convert to string from custom class

Tags: c#, overriding, tostring

This seems like it should be the easiest thing in the world, but I've been away from C# for some time. I'm trying to start a new project, and my dusty old brain is giving me pain over this.

I've created a simple class and I'm trying to override the ToString() method.  What I'm finding is that when creating a Console app, the compiler has no problem converting my objects to string, but when I switch to Windows forms, the compiler balks, and forces me to explicitly call .ToString()  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
David

```cs
public class TestClass1
{
  private Int32 value;

  public TestClass1()
  { value = 0;}

  public override string ToString()
  { return value.ToString(); }
}

public partial class MainForm : Form
{
  public MainForm()
  { InitializeComponent(); }

  private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    TestClass1 test = new TestClass1();
    MessageBox.Show(test.ToString()); // this compiles
    MessageBox.Show(test); // this doesn't
    // Argument 1: Cannot convert TestClass1 to string
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Console.WriteLine()` method has [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.8#System_Console_WriteLine_System_Object_) that takes an `object` as parameter, allowing you to directly pass almost anything into it. Presumably, it then calls `ToString` on the parameter *for you*.

However, [all overloads of `MessageBox.Show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show?view=netframework-4.8) take a `String` as the message, so you can't directly pass your own class into the method.

Comment: Interesting. I assumed the system would call my ToString method and deliver the result to MessageBox.Show.  Anyway, thanks for the reply.